# PHP 7: How to append new field into stdObject but on a specific position?

Tags: php, object

Appending itself is trivial:

```
$obj->lorem = 'ipsum';
```

Assuming the object has properties like `foo` and `bar`, **then `lorem` will be added at the end**. This makes sense but…

How can I insert `lorem` let's say **between** `foo` **and** `bar`?

I assume I have to traverse through object fields, can you shed some light on the most effective approach?

Comment: object variables do not have any sort of ordering

Answer (score -1):

For simple objects, you can use the associative array syntax and casting to get an object.

Example:

```
<?php

$obj = (object)array('lorem' => 'ipsum', 'foo' => 'bar');

echo $obj->lorem;  //echo ipsum

echo "</br></br>";

echo $obj->foo; //echo bar

?>
```